# Fetch data using angularJS $get

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I am trying to use angular js $get to fetch data . I can do it with simple function like this:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('{% url 'ajax-view' %}', function(data) {
            alert(data['revenue']);
        })
    })


</script>


but trying this way in angular. since im new to this. cant get it work.



      <script>

        var app = angular.module('plinc', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
        url: '{% url 'ajax-view' %}',
        method: "GET"
        }).then($scope.getdata = function(response) {
        alert(data['revenue']);
        $scope.data = response;
        });
        });
        </script>
```

here is the full django template:  https://dpaste.de/4Y3y5/

Comment: Using django templates with angular doesn't seem a good idea to me :(. You can replace templates from the Django MTV with angular templates completely.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `$http`s xhr callback methods (then, success, error) should be a callback function, not an expression as you have done. Try this:

```
.then(function(response) {
    alert(response['revenue']);
    $scope.data = response;
});
```

Note: You can also use `$http.get(url)` instead of more verbose

`$http({'method': 'GET', 'url': url})` syntax.

Comment: <script>

    var app = angular.module('plinc', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            url: '{% url 'ajax-view' %}',
            method: "GET"
        }).then(function(response) {
            alert(response['revenue']);
            $scope.data = response;
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Now i am getting alert "undefined" and my templates has duplicate contents :(

Comment: It means that `response.revenue` is undefined. The duplication is exactly what I commented on the question. I didn't check your django template but seems like that too is showing the response on the page along with angular templates. Use only one of them.

Comment: I am new to angular can you fix that part :)

Answer (score 0):

Ref [the doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http), callbacks that registered by `.then()` and `.success()` have different signatures:

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})
// Here response is like {data:..., status:..., headers:..., config:...}
.then(function(response) {})
```

Thus your code could be

```
$http.get('{% url 'ajax-view' %}').then(function(response) {
    alert(response.data.revenue);
    $scope.data = response.data;
});
```

Or

```
$http.get('{% url 'ajax-view' %}').success(function(data) {
    alert(data.revenue);
    $scope.data = data;
});
```